# Redirect my IP to another section of the site using HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all my traffic to a different part of the site and to redirect my IP to the development section, can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ==My IP
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ dev/index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

If i goto mysite.com/index it goes to a 404. If I remove the rewritecond for my IP then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =11.22.33.44
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ dev/index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} =11.22.33.44
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ dev/index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If I wanted to add an extra parameter to it how would I adjust the regex? ie:
RewriteRule  ^([^/.]+)/?$ dev/index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [L,QSA]. I've added action=$2 and want it to take anything after any other slashes. so... mysite.com/index/dothisaction

Comment: What do you think `$2` would be? Can you give an example.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I accidentally posted my msg before I had finished it. I've updated my original comment now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /dev/index.php?page=$1 [L]